# How to get rid of the small window that automatically opens in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Whenever I select a word in Word 2010 and move the cursor up, an annoying floating window appears with fonts, etc. Does anyone know how to remove this feature?

Comment: This windows is called the **Mini Toolbar** which contains formatting options. I guess Word developers decided to have this shown everytime text is selected is because it is assumed that when you select text, you're going to format it.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable that toolbar by doing the following:

1. Go to File → Options
2. Under General, uncheck "Show Mini Toolbar on selection"
3. Click **OK**

[image]